# Kivy error (python 2.7) : sdl2 import error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, kivy, sdl-2

I'm trying to use kivy on my Python 2.7 project (in a PyCharm - Windows 10 environment), but I get the following error.

If someone can help me ? Thanks !

PS : I tried many times uninstalling/reinstalling libraries etc and doing what suggested on posts like this one, but it doesn't work : [Kivy not working (Error: Unable to find any valuable Window provider.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219563/kivy-not-working-error-unable-to-find-any-valuable-window-provider?rq=1)

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\cyril\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-03-25_0.txt
 C:\Users\cyril\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\modules\__init__.py:128: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
   if path not in sys.path:
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module sp�cifi� est introuvable.
  File "C:\Users\cyril\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\cyril\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 26, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Are the error messages complete? There should be an opening parenthesis and probably something more in the first error message (the one with line 59).

Comment: I edited the post with the full error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Problem

It is looking for the Kivy dependencies (e.g. sdl2) in your virtualenv.

## Solution

I have encountered the same problem. I did the following and it solved the problem.

### Environment

- Windows 10
- PyCharm Community
- Python 3.5
- Kivy dependencies installed (*docutils, pygments, pypiwin32, kivy.deps.sdl2, kivy.deps.glew, kivy.deps.gstreamer*) and for Python 3.5+ (*kivy.deps.angle*)

### PyCharm IDE

1. Open the project
2. Click ***File***
3. Click ***Settings...***
4. Click ***Project Interpreter***
5. On the right panel, click the ***drop down list*** for ***Project Interpreter***
6. Select the location where the Python interpreter is installed e.g. ***C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe***
7. Click ***OK*** until you exit the ***Settings*** window
8. ***Run*** your program

### Output

[image: Img01 - SDL2 Error]
[image: Img02 - Python Interpreter Settings Before Change]
[image: Img03 - Python Interpreter Settings Changed]
[image: Img04 - Run Kivy App]
[image: Img05 - SDL2]

Answer (score 3):

if you have not installed all dependencies then the error will occur , Instead of  Project Interpreter use the pycharm terminal 
Then install the following

1.`python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy_deps.sdl2==0.1.* kivy_deps.glew==0.1.*`

2. `python -m pip install kivy_deps.gstreamer==0.1.*`
3. `python -m pip install kivy_deps.angle==0.1.*`
4. `python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1`

Answer (score 1):

Checked everything, reinstalled etc. still no luck, but after using the -d (debug) option the errormessage expanded and suggested there might be another sdl2.dll in the path. After some trial and error I found one in windows\system32. Moving it out of the way made the error disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running the app in virtual environment and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Lets be real, use a virtual environment. Kivys documentation even highly recommends this aswell.

Repeating this step always gives me a runnable kivy-example
First uninstall all kivy-related librarys you already have installed.

```
python -m pip uninstall -y kivy.deps.glew kivy.deps.gstreamer kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.angle
```

Upgrade pip, wheel, setuptools and setuptools

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools virtualenv
```

Create a venv in your project folder and activate it

```
python -m virtualenv venv
venv\Scripts\activate
```

(on bash put "source" in front.)

Install kivys dependecies to your virtual environment.

```
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy_deps.sdl2==0.1.*
```

If you want video and audio support:

```
python -m pip install kivy_deps.gstreamer==0.1.*
```

On Python 3.5+ you can opt to use Angle astead glew, so do either/or:

```
python -m pip install kivy_deps.glew==0.1.*
python -m pip install kivy_deps.angle==0.1.*
```

Install kivy

```
python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1 kivy_examples==1.11.1
```

After that do

```
python venv\share\kivy-examples\demo\showcase\main.py
```

Source: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html

If it still errors with "[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.",
CMD:

```
set USE_SDL2=1
set USE_GSTREAMER=1
```

Terminal:

```
export USE_SDL2=1
export USE_GSTREAMER=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just impossible, tried all that with 3.7 64 on win10, same exception...This thing just doesn't work, guess I will have to try Beeware instead. Disappointing

Answer (score 0):

Instead run in your IDE, try to run the program in cmd or powershell by `python <filename>`. It works for me.