# Kivy 2.0 Installation Difficulties

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

This is my first time trying to use Kivy, and I haven't been able to run a base code.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')


TestApp().run()
```

And my error log is the following:

C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.9.exe C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/python/BeginnerProjects/KivyTest/main.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in

```
C:\Users\Owner\.kivy\logs\kivy_21-02-11_57.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 58, in core_select_lib
    mod = __import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've tried reinstalling Kivy, installing all the dependencies, nothing has changed these results. Does anyone have an idea on how I can fix these?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482753/sdl2-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-and).

I had this error when I didn't give the main file `main.py` name.