# KIvy installation on Pycharm. gives windows error

Tags: python, installation, error-handling, pycharm, kivy

I tried installing kivy using PyCharm. it installed successfully but on running it gives this error.

```
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 58, in core_select_lib
    mod = __import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage
```

I have the latest version of PyCharm ie `2021.1.1` and python 3.9. windows 10.
please provide a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found and \[CRITICAL\] \[App\] Unable to get a Window, abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482753/sdl2-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-and)

Comment: no brother. it gives the same error

Comment: I even tried removing all python versions and installing the latest one. it still gives the same error. On trying to use virtualenv it gives `module not found: No module named kivy` error