# Python/Kivy app to apk on windows - what to do after installing a virtual machine?

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, apk, kivy

I understand that currently there is no way to package a kivy app for android using windows, so I have downloaded a Linux virtual machine. But then what? I haven't found a good step-by-step tutorial for beginners explaining the whole process.

Am I supposed to download Python, PyCharm, Kivy, etc. into the virtual machine, and also copy the all the app files into it? And if so, what's the next step after that? Sorry to be so clueless, but I'm new to coding and app development, and learning mostly from online tutorials. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: [this page](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/) has instructions

Comment: @darkangel - Thanks for the link! I have seen that page before, and unfortunately it's not very beginner-friendly. I couldn't follow it because it skips too many steps along the way.

Comment: @ikolim - Thank you so much for the detailed answer! I get through the first section just fine, but every time I start the virtual machine the cursor freezes and I end up having to shut down windows. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling several times, but always get the same outcome. I'm using the latest version of windows 10 on a computer that is only a few months old, so not sure what else I can do to fix this. :(

Answer (score 3):

You can package Kivy Apps for Android on Windows by doing the following:

## Kivy Buildozer Virtual Machine Setup

1. Download [Kivy Buildozer VM](http://txzone.net/files/torrents/kivy-buildozer-vm-2.0.zip) and unzip the file.
2. Download the version of VirtualBox for your machine from [Oracle VirtualBox download area](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and install it.
3. Download [Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack for all platforms](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.10/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.2.10.vbox-extpack) and install it.
4. Start *VirtualBox*, click on *File* » *Import Appliance...*
5. Select the extracted directory, file named, *Buildozer VM.ovf*
6. Click on *Settings* » *General* » *Advanced* and select *Bidirectional* in the drop-down list for *Shared Clipboard:*, and *Drag'n'Drop:*
7. Click on *Settings* » *Shared Folders* and click *Adds new shared folder.* e.g. Kivy Apps folder.
8. Click on *Settings* » *USB*, check *Enable USB Controller*, checkbox *USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller*, and click *Adds new USB filters* e.g. Acer tablet.

## PyCharm IDE Setup

1. Download [PyCharm Community](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows) and install it.
2. Install [KV Lang Auto-completion and Highlighting](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Setting-Up-Kivy-with-various-popular-IDE%27s)
3. Please refer to [PyCharm Project Interpreter Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466785/kivy-error-python-2-7-sdl2-import-error/49477111#49477111)

## Create a Package for Android

1. Start *VirtualBox*, select *Kivy/Buildozer VM* and click *Start*
2. Password is *kivy*
3. Copy your Kivy App from local machine to a folder in *Home* folder.
4. Double click *Home folder*
5. Double click *Kivy App folder*
6. Right mouse click and select *Open Terminal Here*
7. At Terminal command prompt, type `buildozer init` to create *buildozer.spec* file.
8. Double click *buildozer.spec* file to make changes (e.g. *title*, *package.name*, *log_level = 2*) and save changes.
9. At Terminal command prompt, type `buildozer android debug deploy run`
10. Enjoy!

Comment: This does not work as you say. The virtual machine nor with v34 (stable) nor master work without hacks. The sources have changed as well so the hacks in github/issues are hard to follow. I have spend weeks with this. I am only able to run my applications in launcher. I have not  been able to find instructions to compile android apks that actually works. Nor installing, nor using the virtual machine provided or  installing my own virtual machine. From compiling errors, to not found files. I love the kivy stuff but is utterly frustrating. This is extremely hard to configure.

Comment: If you encountered ***IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory***, the solution can be found at [IOError: Errno 2 No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50814579/ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-build-outputs-apk-yolo-debug-a)

Comment: thanks for reaching back. I saw the hack. I believe that the file has evolved since the hack was posted and the line number now does not match the expected place. I was unsure and decided to stay put. I I will give it a try over the weekend.  Will come back to you with results.