# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: .../build/outputs/apk/yolo-debug.apk'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to create an APK file using Buildozer and I'm getting this error.

Full error log is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==0.33', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1058, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 91, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 103, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 212, in build
    self.target.build_package()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 808, in build_package
    copyfile(join(apk_dir, apk), join(self.buildozer.bin_dir, apk_dest))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/endaiz/PycharmProjects/percent_sum/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/yolo/build/outputs/apk/yolo-debug.apk'
```

I googled it and found this:
https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/632

And the solution here is to fix android.py file but I don't even have it.

Comment: The *android.py* is in folder, */usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/*. Use ***sudo to edit and compile android.py***.

Comment: @ikolim thanks a lot! It did help me to find this file! And I fixed the error with this solution from github.