# How to convert my .py and .kv into the android application on windows

Tags: python, windows, kivy

Currently, I am developing my project that requires me to develop the android app.
For my project, I use Python and Kivy for UI design. Following some tutorial videos on youtube, I know I can turn my project into an android app that can be launched in my android phone, but it can be easily done using linux OS. My question is how can I do that when I am using the Windows OS? And what step do I need to take?

P.S. I heard that it can't be done on Windows OS since few years ago, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I successfully ran a test app on an android phone while using a windows computer using the kivy virtual machine: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android-vm.html

Comment: @terrence: You might want to check this out [package Kivy Apps for Android on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50126562/python-kivy-app-to-apk-on-windows-what-to-do-after-installing-a-virtual-machin/50145180#50145180)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows 10, you can now run buildozer from WSL (ubuntu at least), as it's mostly equivalent to a native linux installation, only minor fixes were necessary.

You could also install Docker and run any linux distribution from there (ubuntu is certainly still the safest choice though).

If you are on an older version of windows, the easiest way is to run a Virtual Machine, again, ubuntu 18.04 is a fine choice.

once you have any of these setup, the usual instructions to setup applies:

```
apt update
apt install -y git zip unzip python3 python3-virtualenv python3-pip openjdk-8-jdk pkg-config autoconf libtool zlib1g-dev

pip install cython buildozer
buildozer android debug
```

The last command has to be run in your app's directory, which you can access once you have setup WSL by using shift+right-click and selecting "open linux shell here" (as seen in https://superuser.com/questions/1066261/how-to-access-windows-folders-from-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows) and running the command inside it.

If you are using a VM, you'll need to setup file sharing with it so it can access your project directory, and run the command inside it.