# Android apk with buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to build an android apk of a python/kivy app, but I'm getting the following errors when I'm building it.

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Please make sure to include all relevant code or error messages in the actual question **as text**, and not in linked images. Also, please try to describe more in detail what you're doing when your error message occurs.

Comment: @João Teixeira: In Windows OS, you have to use a VM e.g. Oracle VirtualBox and import Kivy VM Buildozer to create an APK file.

Comment: @ikolim but there isnt the kivy vm anymore, can you send me a link to it?

Comment: @João Teixeira: Please check [Package Kivy Apps for Android on Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50126562/python-kivy-app-to-apk-on-windows-what-to-do-after-installing-a-virtual-machin/50145180#50145180)