# Having Problems Installing Python-for-Android on Linux Ubuntu 64 vm

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, sdk, kivy

I installed everything according to https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/

but ended up getting the error I posted.  Can someone please help me get p4a installed....

Linux Ubuntu 64 VM on Win7 64

I tried pip install --user pipenv

Same error.

This returned unknown command: sudo -H pip3.6 install -U pipenv

kivy@kivy-VirtualBox:~$ pip install python-for-android
Downloading/unpacking python-for-android
  Downloading python-for-android-0.7.0.tar.gz (1.6MB): 1.6MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_kivy/python-for-android/setup.py) egg_info for package python-for-android
    error in python-for-android setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    error in python-for-android setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers

---

Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_kivy/python-for-android
Storing debug log for failure in /home/kivy/.pip/pip.log
kivy@kivy-VirtualBox:~$

==============Update=========================

I ran the p4a install with sudo and it installed.  I then got an error about sh 1.10 so I rand pip and installed that.  Now I'm getting the error,

```
Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI: 26
[ERROR]:   Build failed: Could not find `android` or `sdkmanager` binaries 
in Android SDK
[INFO]:    Instructions: Make sure the path to the Android SDK is correct
kivy@kivy-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/HCU$ 
kivy@kivy-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/HCU$ p4a apk --public $HOME/code/myapp -- 
package=org.shieltresst.hcuwts --name "Hein's Catch Up" --version 0.1 -- 
bootstrap=sd12 --requirements=python2,kivy
[WARNING]: $ANDROIDNDKVER is deprecated and no longer necessary, the value 
you set is ignored
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI: 26
[ERROR]:   Build failed: Could not find `android` or `sdkmanager` binaries 
in Android SDK
[INFO]:
```

In my Documents folder I have the android NDK, build toos and tools folders.  In the bashrc, I have the tokens:

```
export ANDROIDSDK="$HOME/kivy/Documents/android-sdk-27"
export ANDROIDNDK="$HOME/kivy/Documents/android-ndk-r17c"
export ANDROIDAPI="26"
export NDKAPI="19"
export ANDROIDNDKVER="r17c"
```

I'm guessing I have something wrong because the p4a docs didn't say android studio had to be downloaded and as for the SDK, it said only the tools where needed.

===============UpDate====================

Apparently I don't even have a real android-sdk dir and creating one and dropping the tools/build-tools in doesn't work.

Do I need to download the full Android Studio and then use its manager to download the SDK?

Comment: You don't need Android Studio, you do need an SDK with build tools and the platform-tools for your target API. If you use buildozer, it should handle this part for you.

Comment: @chitondihk: Please check out [Kivy Buildozer Virtual Machine Setup for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50126562/python-kivy-app-to-apk-on-windows-what-to-do-after-installing-a-virtual-machin/50145180#50145180) and [Kivy Buildozer Commands](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer).

Comment: Buildozer is broken and I'm moving away from that.  I have p4a installed, I just need the android-sdk folder.  I actually got p4a working before in the past and even then, I had android studio installed.  In fact, the android studio site doesn't just let you download the sdk anymore.  You have to do it through android studio.