# I tried to build app with buildozer kivy, but i have an error

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to make android app using kivy.
I downloaded kivy buildozer VM setup and did steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50126562/python-kivy-app-to-apk-on-windows-what-to-do-after-installing-a-virtual-machin/50145180#50145180)
but I get this error:

```
# Cwd /home/kivy/Desktop/ekek/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/kivy/Desktop/ekek/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 96, in <module>
    from pythonforandroid.distribution import Distribution, pretty_log_dists
  File "pythonforandroid/distribution.py", line 48
    *,
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/kivy/Desktop/ekek/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
#
```

I have tried changing python3 in buidozer spec file to python 2 but i didn't change anything.
I still have this error.

Comment: You're running buildozer with python2 or a too-old version of python3. Use Python 3.6 or higher.

Comment: Try this manual https://blog.kivy.org/2019/05/running-buildozer-in-a-virtual-machine/ there were some changes for support of python3 in summer 2018

Comment: Thank you :) I did that manual and it helped but I got new error: "No module named _ctypes" ;/