# simple kivy app gives me an error (pycharm)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, kivy

so iam trying to start with kivy. so i first tried to just run an simple code, but it does give me an error i cant fix?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Test")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

if i run this code the console gives me this output:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Gamer\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-11-19_85.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Gamer\PycharmProjects\TimeDrillerv1\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Gamer\PycharmProjects\TimeDrillerv1\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
  File "C:\Users\Gamer\PycharmProjects\TimeDrillerv1\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Gamer\PycharmProjects\TimeDrillerv1\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_sdl2.py", line 13, in <module>
    from kivy.core.text._text_sdl2 import (_SurfaceContainer, _get_extents,

pil - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
  File "C:\Users\Gamer\PycharmProjects\TimeDrillerv1\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Gamer\PycharmProjects\TimeDrillerv1\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_pil.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Your kivy isn't installed/compiled properly. How did you install it?

Comment: once i installed it on my windows with following the steps on the kivy website.

Comment: secondly i installed kivy in pycharm with using the project interpreter

Comment: PIL module is missing `pip install pillow`

Comment: @abhilb okay thanks . worked, but now i get [CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

Comment: You don't need pil/pillow, that comment is wrong. It sounds like you need to install kivy properly in the pycharm environment, make sure you install all the same things instructed by the kivy website.

Comment: thats right. i had a wrong directory in pycharm for the project

Answer (score 0):

try

```
pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
pip install kivy.deps.angle
```

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5859

Enable debug level logging to check detailed report of what is failing.

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'log_level', 'debug')
Config.write()
```

Comment: didnt worked for me. i use pycharm and it looks like it doesnt chaned anythink at all ;p

Comment: does it still show Unable to get a Window?

Comment: i have found the solution for the window problem. and it was because of pycharm. it used the python37 - 32 directory to get the installed modules, while pip installs everythink into python37 - 65 (bit)      so i changed the directory and now it works :)

Comment: heres the post with the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466785/kivy-error-python-2-7-sdl2-import-error